# Modifying Column Charts in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I was wondering if someone might be able to help me figure out how to create a particular chart in excel. The rows are businesses and the columns are what percentage of people in area A and B that use that business. Where it gets tricky is that the table looks like this:

```
     Area A  Extra A Area B Extra B
ONE   2%      0%       8%        0%
TWO   8%      0%       5%        0%
THREE 15%     0%       3%        0%
FOUR  20%     5%       25%       5%
FIVE  20%     0%       15%       0%
```

When I try to just create a new chart I get separate columns for each of these four columns as expected. What I'd like though is for the 5% in Extra A and Extra B to 'cap off' the numbers from Area A and Area B. So there should only be two separate columns and two caps for business FOUR (and no others since they're all 0%). How might I go about this?

Comment: This would be easier to follow if you add a table that reflects how you are trying to interpret or use the data.  What do you mean by "cap off"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty -

You can spread out your data a bit as shown below. When you insert a stacked column chart, and set the gap width of the column series to 0%, you get a chart like that shown below.

[image: Spread out data to get a clustered-stacked column chart]

Longer answer -

I wrote a tutorial showing how to get a decent looking [Clustered and Stacked Column Chart in Excel](http://peltiertech.com/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/).